# How to handle android keyboard actions

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android.  I am trying to make a text box and on pressing done key, it should take the value to the java code. For this I am using setOnEditorActionListener.. I searched on how to do this and got many answers on how to implement it. Example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

I need to ask where should I write this thing? In which method? I tried doing it in onCreate but it threw some error. I somehow made it work using this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.unlock);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            Log.i(TAG, "button pressed");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hey you just clicked the DONE button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;  
      }
```

Here I used **this** keyword, and I don't understand why have I used it. 
Question 1. Please help me understand, why have we used this keyword..

Question 2. Why wasn't it working in the below code?

```
 public void checkInput() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Enter checkInput method");

        final EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Enter onEditorAction");
                boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "button pressed")
                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
    }
```

I called this checkInput method from onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer Question 1:

> Here I used this keyword, and I don't understand why have I used it. Question 1. Please help me understand, why have we used this keyword..

You're telling Java to look into the Activity class for implementations of methods required by the `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` interface. So for all interactions with your soft keyboard, Java would look into your class for the method: `onEditorAction`

In order for the above to work, your activity needs to defined like:

`public class MyActivity implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {}`

For question 2:

> Question 2. Why wasn't it working in the below code?

To check for the "Done" action, your `if` statement should be:

`if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) { ... }`

Hope that helps.

Comment: That means "this" keyword here is sending instance of onEditorAction of my class? And for Q2, I am checking for IME_ACTION_SEND only, then why isn't it working?

Comment: In your XML file, set `android:imeOptions="actionSend"`